# Replacing text in non selected lines

Tags: vimrc, conceal

I have `\begin{thm}` in a lot of my `.tex` files. Whenever I am not in the selected line I would like this to be rendered as `Theorem`.

I have tried using conceal but it is limited to rendering a single character.

Does anybody know how to achieve this effect?

Comment: "I have tried using ..." - please [edit] and tell us *exactly* what you tried and how it failed. Thank you.

Comment: @Friedrich a failing solution is not required to answer this question, which is "how do I turn `\begin{thm}` into `Theorem` when the cursor isn't on the line?" [I believe the answer is "you can't," but even an affirmative answer doesn't require starting from the OP's failed attempt?] This isn't [so], where a programming question should show the failing program.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble accepted. I didn't understand the question until after I posted my comment. Sometimes the failure hints at what OP is trying to achieve. Sometimes they're almost there. In either case, having all the information on the table helps. Not in this case, though.